# Why is certificate invalid for one .net core web api project only?

Tags: asp.net-core, https, swagger, ssl-certificate, asp.net-core-webapi

I have .Net solution with two .Net core web API projects in it.
Both projects have swagger set up and for both projects, the HTTP URL works fine.

However, for the HTTPS URL, it works for one project but not the other.
The certificate is deemed invalid by the browser for the project that sees the error.

I've looked for a solution for hours and tried the following commands but could not make it work.

```
dotnet dev-certs https --clean
dotnet dev-certs https
dotnet dev-certs https --trust
```

If I check the existence of the cert and if it is trusted, with `dotnet dev-certs https -c -t`, I see that the cert is present and trusted.

Then, using `dotnet run`, I have no compiling issue or anything but in the browser, only one of the project works and displays the swagger HTTPS page ...

I don't think I understand enough how certificates work between the browser and .net core to understand why I'm having this issue.

Do you have any idea how to fix it?

Here are a few observations that I hope may help:

- The projects are identical and were simply created with Visual Studio, so that should not be something in the code that's in the way.
- I don't see any certificate in the windows certificate manager. Since it works for one project, I don't understand where the certificate is stored.
- If I clean the certificates and check again, it tells me that, as expected, there is no certificate found. After that, if I run `dotnet run` on each project, the one that used to work gives me an error saying it could not generate the https endpoints. That makes sense since the certificate is not present anymore. However, the one that was not working before I remove the certificates does not give me an error and runs like if nothing happened (though of course, still not working) ... I suspect it's not trying to create the https endpoint but I don't know why.

Do you know why one project would work and not another?
Where is the HTTPS endpoint created and what triggers that creation?

Comment: Which way do you  configure https for your project ? And please check the two projects's difference . Besides, you can read [Enforce HTTPS in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio) to know more.

Comment: @QingGuo I'm not trying to use HTTPS just yet, though Swagger seems to work fine with it on one project. I've disabled redirectToHttps for the moment and that would be for my API anyway, right? Here, I'm just checking Swagger's page and my understanding is that it should work or not work with HTTPS consistently ... here, the difference in behavior is what puzzles me ...

Comment: you are using docker compose or docker to run the application? both project are created on the same machine with same OS? we need more information.

Comment: Docker is set up but I'm still at the first stage of development so I run the application locally with ```dotnet run```. Again, the issue is not with the application so far as I haven't set up HTTPS. I'm just trying to understand why the certificate is accepted for the swagger page for one project but not the other.